# How can i switch to parameters tab in jmeter (http post request) after recorded the login feature

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I recorded the login feature and open the http post request which I got. It shows the credential values in the "body data" tab. It is displayed in the image:
[image: i recorded the login feature and open the http post request which i got. it shows the credential values in the "body data" tab. it is displayed in the image]

When I try to switch to parameter tab, it shows a pop up message . Please observe the 2nd image:
[image: when i try to switch to parameter tab, it shows a pop up message . please observe the 2nd image]

I would like to know that how can I move to parameters tab, so that I could use regular expression for the dynamic value(csrf). Hope issue is clear.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that other users know they can trust it

Answer (score 1):

You can move by cutting current text in body so that it's empty.

But why do you want to do that. It seems you vave a REST request here and that it requires a body.

You can add if needed a parameter in url path, but as it wasn't recorded I am not sure it's needed.

Maybe XCSRF is required in Header, so use a HeaderManager

Comment: This was my issue as well, the tricky part was that I had a few newlines in the body, so it seemed empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to `move to parameters tab` in order to use the Regular Expression Extractor, you should be extracting the dynamic value from the **server's response**, not from your own request. If it really annoys you you can delete it from the "Body Data" tab and place the request in "Parameters" tab like this:

   [image: JMeter JSON Parameters]
2. Most probably you don't need the Regular Expression Extractor as well, since JMeter 3.0 there is [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which should be a better fit when it comes to [JSON data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) correlation.

---

Be aware of the alternative way of recording a JMeter test which is capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and handling of dynamic parameters, it might make your life easier, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more information on the approach.